# Biking in Arizona: Homebase in Phoenix or Scottsdale?

Tags: cities, bicycles, arizona

I have two days of vacation before a conference in Scottsdale, Arizona and I'd love to spend them biking in the area. For (single day) biking trips in the nature, what are the pros and cons of each place?

Comment: Hi Holger, welcome.  At present your question is a bit too subjective.   There are people on here who like luxury hotels, while others will cling to the back of a bus to cross a border.  Questions like "would you recommend getting a hotel" and "does it matter" can't be answered objectively.  Could you please rephrase it for your situation, so that people can then objectively answer it (see [faq] for more tips) and then flag it to be reopened - and we'll be happy to help!

Comment: I think he is asking if it is better to get a hotel in Scottsdale or Phoenix for the purpose of biking. I can't see any parts where he is asking whether to stay in a hotel or somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you want relatively flat trails or mountain biking, as you didn't say.

The [Scottsdale Green Belt](http://www.yelp.com/biz/scottsdale-green-belt-scottsdale) is a paved trail several miles in length that begins just north of Shea Boulevard and ends in Tempe.  There are only a few places on the trail that require crossing a street, as there are lots of tunnels that pass below busy streets.

There would be dozens of hotels located along this path, ranging from simple motel-like accommodations to pricey resorts.  [Here is a map](http://www.scottsdaleaz.gov/Assets/Public+Website/traffic/Bicycles/IBW_SharedUsePaths.pdf) of the path and various connections.

For mountain biking, I recommend South Mountain in Phoenix which is the largest city park in the world.  There are more than [10 different trails](http://phoenix.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=phoenix&cdn=citiestowns&tm=48&f=11&su=p554.21.342.ip_&tt=2&bt=0&bts=0&zu=http://mountainbikeaz.com/trail_reviews/phx_smtn.php) in South Mountain ranging from 1 mile in length to 14 miles (58 miles total).  Difficulty ranges from moderate to difficult.  There are also several hotels/resorts in the South Mountain area.  You could also check for accommodations in the [Ahwatukee area](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=ahwatukee,%20az) of Phoenix just south of the mountain.

Note that it is just starting to warm up here -- late April and it was over 100 °F (38 °C) here today (I live in Gilbert, just SE of Phoenix).  The forecast for next week is mostly high 90's to low 100's °F (35-40 °C); it's just going to gradually get hotter.  So take LOTS of water with you.